# How to clone all specific record and modify one of the columns

Tags: sql

I'm working on a multi lingual system using database ,
am Trying to clone all record with specific language_id 'EN' , and clone into same table but different language_id with same key_value and key text

table language

```
id---language_id---key_value---key_text
1        EN        _WELCOME    Welcome              
2        CH        _WELCOME      ...            
3        EN        _LOG_IN     Log In               
4        CH        _LOG_IN       ...
```

Did some workhome , but its not working , not sure this is right way of doing the job.

```
INSERT INTO language (language_id,key_value,key_text)
(SELECT 'FR','key_value','key_text' FROM language  WHERE language_id='EN' )

//Unknown column 'language_id' in 'where clause'
```

I got this sample from some old webs tutorial , but they are working on different table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to insert all `'EN'` data as `'FR'`, Try; **T-Sql**

```
INSERT INTO language (language_id,key_value,key_text)
SELECT 'FR' as language_id, key_value, key_text 
FROM language  WHERE language_id='EN'
```

Comment: Well, it selects the `key_value`, `key_text` with the `static value 'FR'` filtered by `'EN'` and Insert them with the mapping. In your query nothing being selected from language table as they were all static values.

Comment: Sorry i think your answer are seems quite right , but still i cant get it work , is there any good way to debug this...I'm using mysql4 and php5 , no really experience at this

Comment: This query should work, Check the query string if it is matching the above before submitting. It could be something to do with `'` (may be `''` work). I am not a php guy.

Comment: You are right the query are fine , corrected some naming , and its work now , thanks for the knowledge